Looking for a python library to get the TEXT CURSOR position. Not mouse pointer position
I am looking for a script in python that helps me, HOW get the position of the TEXT cursor?.
I am not looking for the MOUSE pointer position.
Usually many python libraries help you to find the cordinates of the screen positon of the MOUSE pointer, but I don't need that.
I need the TEXT CURSOR that you can find in a cell of excel or in a text box of a windows software formulary, or in a text box of a web formulary.
I am filling automatically with python library "pyautogui" a Formulary under WINDOWS and I need to know if the text cursor is in a certain position of that formulary to write some values.
Remember that the mouse pointer can be parked in a corner of the screen and when I run the script of the library "pyautogui" in order to fill a formulary with data automatically, the text cursor is runing over all the text boxes of this formulary and setting data. This formulary is in a WINDOWS app.
Please if you can help me and want to write the python script that do that, check it first on your computer before to post it. Thank you.
